# How to put " character into a string literal?

Tags: java, string

I need to put `"` into a string literal in Java like the followig:

```
String a = "'"'Some string'"'";
```

Since google don't handle search request like `String java "` or `String literal java "` because of the charcter `"` I decided to ask about it here.

Comment: escape it: `"\"Some string\""`

Comment: [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html) will help you further...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `\"`

```
String a = "__HERE_SHOULD_BE_\"Some string__HERE_SHOULD_BE_\"";
```